# Prevent a new intent or switching apps from destroying a activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, ondestroy

I have a activity where I do nothing with the following function (onPause/onStop/onDestroy). It is just how it was when you create a activity from scratch.

Now when I switch to a new app or I start a new activity with a new intent the activity is destroyed. The android system calls onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy.

How can I prevent the app from calling onDestory on that specific activity?

**Code for starting the new activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

**Manifest code:**

```
    <activity android:name=".WebviewActivity">
    </activity>
```

As you can see I have nothing in there.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you use to start the second activity?

Comment: @Sagar Ofcourse! Thank you.

Comment: Have you set any flags for this activity in Manifest.xml? Also you are not calling `finish ()` anywhere right?

Comment: Look into your first activity launch mode in manifest file and the intent flag used to start first activity. https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242

Comment: @Segar, no, I never call finish() in this activity. Also I have not set any flags in the manifest file for this activity.

Comment: no,you can not prevent these methods from being called,they are part of android activity lifecycle.why do you want the activity to persist?there are ways to make the data in an activity persist and you can use them to recreate your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you didn't accidentally enabled "don't keep activities" mode in developer options:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUXPG.png]

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't, these are life cycles method called by Android environment, and you donot have any control over it. The Android runtime decides when to call these methods.

You are launching activity via Implicit call , so the android runtime determines the best suitable activity for it, and that activity may run in its own stack, which may cause calling of onDestroy on your activity,  as its no more visible.

Ankit